# Agendamento de Tarefas no Django

Tags: python, django

Galera é o seguinte, no Django as coisas só acontecem quando algum usuário acessa sua aplicação.

**UM EXEMPLO (*fictício*)**

Imaginemos que você criou uma aplicação em que o usuário entra e grava pequenos textos de lembrete, mais ou menos como se fossem um post-it, para ele consultar todo dia e verificar as atividades que não pode se esquecer.

O usuário precisa entrar na aplicação para consultar seus lembretes para a data atual e para adicionar novos lembretes para datas futuras.

**A NOVA NECESSIDADE**

Agora imaginem que vocês querem implementar uma nova funcionalidade para que todo dia sua aplicação envie por e-mail uma listagem dos lembretes do usuário para daquele dia que está iniciando.

**A REFLEXÃO SOBRE O CASO**

Veja que originalmente todas as ações que ocorrem na aplicação dependem de um acesso do usuário, mas para essa nova funcionalidade nós precisaremos que o sistema inicie uma ação automaticamente sem esperar uma ação de usuário.

Seria um espécie de serviço rodando que todo dia em um determinado horário verificasse os lembretes de cada usuário, preparasse cada mensagem e as enviasse.

**O QUE EU PENSEI EM FAZER**

Me passou pela cabeça criar uma thread que fica rodando o tempo todo em paralelo e que ao chegar no horário programado dispara as rotinas necessárias.

Parece fazer algum sentido, mas eu não tenho certeza se existe uma opção melhor pra fazer isso e ainda qual seriam os prós e contras dessa estrutura, além de algum possível impacto no consumo de recursos do sistema.

> **Importate:** Eu não tenho nenhuma dificuldade em preparar as rotinas que executam
>   as ações (verificar os lembretes, preparar as mensagens e enviar os
>   e-mails), meu problema é sobre como criar esse agendamento que vai
>   disparar esse processo automaticamente.

**Vocês já precisaram criar algo assim com Django, como fizeram?**

Comment: O ideal é agendar uma tarefa no SO (ex.: em sistemas *NIX, via cron) que chama um comando do Django (ex.: [via `manage.py`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/pt-br/1.11/howto/custom-management-commands/)) que então faz o que você quer. Ou então usar uma ferramenta tipo o [Celery](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html) (nunca usei, mas pelo que andei pesquisando é o modo mais recomendado para isso). P.S. Não dou uma resposta mais completa porque não tenho experiência prática.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O [Tutorial Básico do Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/pt-br/1.11/intro/tutorial01/) orienta a criação de um custom command para a execução de rotinas externas. No seu caso, pela descrição do problema, creio que você pode seguir nessa linha. Aqui segue o link para [Escrevendo comandos personalizados do django-admin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/pt-br/1.11/howto/custom-management-commands/) que tem uma explicação detalhada sobre o assunto.

Em linhas gerais você terá que:

1. Escrever seu Command:

   ```
   class Command(BaseCommand):
       help = 'Command Customizado Teste'

       def add_arguments(self, parser):
           parser.add_argument('parametro', nargs='+', type=str)

       def handle(self, *args, **options):
           print("Chamou a execução deste command")
           print(options['parametro'])
   ```
2. Colocar o Command no diretório management/commands do seu app (no exemplo do Django (dir_projeto)/polls/management/commands). O nome do comando será o nome do arquivo (módulo) que você criou.
3. Para verificar se o seu Command foi reconhecido pelo Django, digite python manage.py. Você verá algo similar a isso:

   ```
   Type 'manage.py help <subcommand>' for help on a specific subcommand.

   Available subcommands:

   [auth]
       changepassword
       createsuperuser

   [seu app]
       seu_command

   [django]
       check
       compilemessages
       createcachetable
       dbshell
       diffsettings
       dumpdata
       flush
       inspectdb
       loaddata
       makemessages
       makemigrations
       migrate
       sendtestemail
       shell
       showmigrations
       sqlflush
       sqlmigrate
       sqlsequencereset
       squashmigrations
       startapp
       startproject
       test
       testserver

   [sessions]
       clearsessions

   [staticfiles]
       collectstatic
       findstatic
       runserver
   ```
4. Para executá-lo utilize ([verifique a documentação sobre parâmetros](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#module-argparse)):

   ```
   python manage.py seu_command "seu parametro"
   ```
5. Por fim, após finalizado e testado o seu Command, agende a execução dele no crontab ou agendador de tarefas do SO que você utiliza.